# awesome_nested_set gem level db column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using the awesome_nested_set gem and I have read somewhere (can't find it now) that all you need to do is add a level column to the database and it will add the level automatically.

It will create the level if I run

```
Subject.rebuild!
```

But I want it to do it when I create new ones.

I have tried the following too with no success.

```
before_save do
  self.level = ancestors.count
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just a similar problem, trying to access `self_and_ancestors` within a `before_save` callback.

The problem is that the child record hasn't been created yet at the DB level, but `self_and_ancestors` (which, incidentally, is also referenced by `ancestors`) queries the DB, expecting our new child to already have been created...

Catch-22.

EDIT:

It's ugly, but as a work-around for this limiation of awesome_nested_set, this should work for the OP (provided the parent already exists):

```
before_save do
    self.level = self.parent.self_and_ancestors.count
end
```